# The way to work with browser DOM in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-template

I have a weak grasp of how should I work with native DOM elements if I want to create a global DOM Element and use it from many instances of the current directive?

Can someone explain the working with directives and the DOM please?

Comment: Angular 2 has a benefit that you can work with DOM the way you will in vanlila JavaScript inside angular's code as well. No specific practice is required.

Comment: But how the testing process of such a directive should go?

Comment: Sorry bro but I don't have knowledge of testing. Although you can start from "how to test web components" articles on google. Coz angular is now using webcomponents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to grab the element associated with a component

```
import {Component, View, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration'
})

@View({
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})

export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.moving-box').draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
    }
}
```

Using ElementRef as your baseline you can use jquery or any other DOM manipulation technique to reference other elements.

This sample uses jquery.

Here is some more info:
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you clarify - how should I test this? I mean - in the first angular there is a $window service, that I can mock. Is there something analogous here or i should take completely different approach in the second angular?